# Facebook redirect to non secure version of page tab after login

Tags: facebook, http, redirect, https

I'm developing a Facebook app which is hosted on a secure server, but since the app requests for permission, the user must be logged to access, but when the user logs into facebook the url redirects from this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/mypage/app_xxxxxxxx
```

to this:

```
http://www.facebook.com/mypage/app_xxxxxxxx
```

Them I get a 404 error. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a user setting and one which Facebook is forcing a change on shortly.

http://techcrunch.com/2012/11/18/facebook-https/